# Настройка окон

Tags: windows-7

Проблема такая, не могу настроить окна в семерке, чтобы они открывались в одном и том же окне. Настройки папок верные. То есть стоит галочке, где написано открывать в том же окне, но все равно открывается в новом окне.

Как это и с чем это связано?

Comment: @bsdmacs упс, сорри...учте..ошибка вышла...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно настройки в реестре сбились. Можно попробовать выполнить этот [reg-файл](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/reg/samefolderwindow.reg) (вообще он для Windows XP, но может и на Windows 7 сработает).